# Select object by field and print parent key in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I'm looking to find a way to pull the parent key name from a JSON list that looks something like this:

```json
{
    "london1.perfect-privacy.com": {
        "city": "London",
        "city_short": "lo",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "country_short": "gb",
        "lati": "51.511214",
        "longi": "-0.119824"
    },
    "london2.perfect-privacy.com": {
        "city": "London",
        "city_short": "lo",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "country_short": "gb",
        "lati": "51.511214",
        "longi": "-0.119824"
    },
    "rotterdam2.perfect-privacy.com": {
        "city": "Rotterdam",
        "city_short": "ro",
        "country": "Netherlands",
        "country_short": "nl",
        "lati": "51.924216",
        "longi": "4.481776" 
    }
}
```

Parent keys in this case are server names, and want to use JQ by to pull these over by selecting a specific country.  This code below lets me pull all the parent keys, but I'm having trouble narrowing it down to just those that belong to a specific country:

```bash
jq -r 'keys' serverlocations.json
```

Results:

```
london1.perfect-privacy.com
london2.perfect-privacy.com
rotterdam2.perfect-privacy.com
```

So when I try something like this, I get a big fat error...

```bash
jq -r 'keys | select(.country == "United Kingdom")' serverlocations.json"
```

Error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "country"
```

I would have expected and want these results back:

```
london1.perfect-privacy.com
london2.perfect-privacy.com
```

Your advice and expertise is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
path(.[] | select(.country == "United Kingdom"))[0]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AvKnPxwRSII)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
to_entries[] | select( .value.country_short == "gb" ) | .key
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/isCbmTdOUTP) on jqplay